# What is the Jaffa armour made of?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, jaffa

From its appearance and the sounds it generates the Jaffa's armour seems to be made largely of a metallic chain-mail-like armour. However we regularly see the Jaffa armour shrug off bullets, suggesting it is something much stronger than the chain-mail we have here on Earth.

[image: Horus Jaffa]

Is this ever addressed in canon as to what it is made of?

Comment: Shrug off bullets? All those dead Jaffa full of lead seems to negate that

Comment: Cakes? Jaffa cake- You know waht, ignore me.

Comment: cde, in the opening scenes Children of the Gods despite the barrage of bullets, Apophis, Teal'c and two other Jaffa leave unharmed. And Teal'c turns his back to protect Carol Weterings, and the bullets just bounce off his back.

Comment: It's probably a Naquada compound like *literally every other advanced thing the Goa'uld built*.

Comment: Robotnik I thought about that, but Naquadah is very rare so I'm not sure they would waste it on Jaffa armour. And considering how hard it was for the SGC to find Naquadah if it was in Jaffa armour then surely they would have just taken the armour from the Jaffa they killed? Though perhaps they reserve the Naquadah armour for Goa'ulds and the first prime, which would explain why Teal'c and Apophis survived the first encounter so easily. I'd still need to see some canon evidence though as this is just explanation.

Comment: @moogle - I don't feel like my answer truly deserved the bounty here since its lacking a canon source. If a better answer is posted, I'll offer a bounty of 100 rep.

Comment: @Moogle it stands to reason the SG teams started using armor-piercing rounds as standard after the original encounter with Jaffa where standard rounds were ineffective.

Comment: @ChadLevy That's an interesting point. I'm currently rewatching SG1 in its entirety so I'll look out to see if the phenomenon happens again.

Answer (score 5):

Within the [show scripts](http://www.imsdb.com/TV/Stargate%20SG1.html), I can't find any references to the armor other than that it's "*metal*". That's it for the EU Novels too.

Out of universe, the metal plates of the Jaffa armour were made from a polymerised rubber, sprayed silver to look like metal. The chain mail was real though, made from plated steel rings.

Comment: I always thought they looked like rubber/foam. Do you have any canon examples that specifically mention that it is metal? I can't find any.

Comment: @moogle - There's some passing references in the scripts to "clanking" and the books say something about the Jaffa "in their metal armour" but beyond that, basically nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Metal superior to that of what we are able to make on Earth, likely because Goa'uld know more about metals than Tau'ri have developed, but still susceptible to armor piercing rounds. Likely still cheaply made by their standards and easily mass produced. This is why the weapons fire in early episodes just had no effect. FMJ is just deflected.

Comment: Do you have any evidence it is indeed metal that you could [edit] in? Bullets can deflect off of more than just metal.